# Capitalizing Postal Codes in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to capitalize a large vector of Canadian Postal Codes in a dataframe. I have an idea of how to do it, but i'm not sure how to write the for loop for it.  Canadian postal codes follow an alphanumeric format 'A1A 1A1'.

Let's say my data looks like this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 1))
df$V1 <- c('a1a 1a1','b1b 1b1','c1c 1c1','d1d 1d1','e1e 1e1','f1f 1f1','g1g 
1g1','h1h 1h1','i1i 1i1','j1j 1j1')
colnames(df) <- 'PostalCodes'
```

I have figured out that you can capitalize using the following:

```
x <- c('a1a 1a1')
s <- strsplit(x," ")[[1]]
output <- paste0(toupper(substr(s,1,1)), toupper(substr(s,2,2)), 
toupper(substr(s,3,3)),  collapse = " ")
```

However I would like to run a for loop over a vector and not just 1 value.  I know what iterators do in a for loop, but I am having trouble as to how to use them and how to store outputs.

Thanks so much!

Comment: `toupper` is vectorized.  Just do this:  `toupper(df$PostalCodes)`.

Comment: digits are neglected with toupper function

Comment: @Dan Y, thanks for the info, I definitely overthought this....